# Changing the text/background color through JavaScript immediately changes back

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to change text color and background color of the text according to what I write in the textbox. Seems to work briefly; it shows me the color for a split second, like a quick snap and that's it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prelab5 Ex1</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Prelab5 Ex1</h2>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="background" id="background"/><input type="submit" value="Background" onclick="changeBack();"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text"/><input type="submit" onclick="changeText();" value="Text"/>
    <br/>
    <div id="content">Some text</div>
</form> 

<script>
var DivText = document.getElementById("content");
function changeBack(){
    var backColor = (document.getElementById("background").value);
    DivText.style.backgroundColor= backColor;
}

function changeText(){
    var textColor = (document.getElementById("text").value);
    DivText.style.color = textColor;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` handlers for your submit buttons don't `return false` so your form is submitted resetting the page. You could add `return false` like

```js
var DivText = document.getElementById("content");

function changeBack() {
  var backColor = (document.getElementById("background").value);
  DivText.style.backgroundColor = backColor;
}

function changeText() {
  var textColor = (document.getElementById("text").value);
  DivText.style.color = textColor;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prelab5 Ex1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Prelab5 Ex1</h2>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="background" id="background" />
    <input type="submit" value="Background" onclick="changeBack(); return false" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="changeText(); return false" value="Text" />
    <br/>
    <div id="content">Some text</div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cheers. Indeed, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your "submit" input performs the action on the form, which is currently set to "post". This will post the form to the same page (and cause a refresh).

You can override the default functionality by adding `return false;` to the ONCLICK attribute on all `input type=  "submit"` elements.

In other words, this:

needs to become this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="changeText();" value="Text"/>
```

but why use input type = submit at all?

You can just as easily use a link or button without the form:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeText();"/>Test</a>
```

or 
Click me!

which will do the same thing without needing to override the a forum action :)